# Three.js ligthing has recessed areas more lighted than surfaces

Tags: three.js

The Rubik's Cube I've modeled using STL parts is lighted from all 6 directions with directional lights. As can be seen, the recessed areas are more lighted than the surfaces. When I load and position the STL files into Blender, rendering is fine. So I think the files are OK.

So, how can I fix lighting? Note that setting castShadows/receiveShadows on light and materials (phong/lambert/standard) doesn't seem to change anything.

Code is at https://github.com/ittayd/rubiks_trainer/blob/master/js/three-cube.mjs#L134

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hmm... Before you add the STL data to its Mesh, try using [`computeVertexNormals`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.computeVertexNormals) on all returned geometry. It _looks like_ the normals aren't right. Blender won't have a problem with these because it uses face normals to light the surfaces, while three.js shaders use vertex normals.

Comment: Tried it, didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're seeing makes sense. When a face is pointing straight down the axis they're only affected by the light in front of them. But when a face is halfway between axes, it's affected by more than one light, creating an additive effect. You could minimize this by adding shadows, but creating a new shadowmap for 3 lights is expensive.

- The Rubik's cube has 26 pieces * 3 lights = 78 drawcalls
- +26 pieces for the final render = 104 drawcalls per frame!

I recommend you just bake an ambient occlusion map with Blender, then use that in your material [with `.aoMap`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=phong#api/en/materials/MeshPhongMaterial.aoMap) to simulate those darker crevasses very cheaply, and keep your performance smooth. Once you have your AO map, you can just use a single `ambientLight` to illuminate everything, without needing 5 different lights (More lights = more expensive renders).

[image]

Comment: So I guess I now need to learn to use Blender (just downloaded it to ask this question) and what is an occlusion map... ;-)

Comment: @ittayD Or you could just paint black interiors with vertex colors like this rubiks demo: There are a lot of workarounds you could use. https://playcanv.as/p/V9B7k46n/